# Call to undefined method

Tags: module, administrator, troubleshooting, dashboard, joomla-3.10

I've have a big problem with my dashbord SP Page Builder, when i tried to go on https://www.sologne-nature.org/administrator/index.php?option=com_sppagebuilder , i've got this message `0 Call to undefined method SppagebuilderViewPages::getSortFields()`  and i can't modify my pages anymore. I've did somes research without any results. Can you help me to resolve it please ? I don't know where to go in my files to fix it.

I'm on joomla 3.10.11 and using sp page builder 4.0.9 and helix ultimate 2.0.12.

Comment: If you turn on Debug and Error Messages in the Global configuration it will provide more details such as the file and line number where the problem is occurring. Have you contacted the vendor?

Comment: I did what you said and got this :
Une erreur s'est produite

    0 Call to undefined method SppagebuilderViewPages::getSortFields()
    /home2/lach3224/public_html/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/views/pages/tmpl/default.php:32

Comment: and this under : 
Call stack
#  Function  Location
1  ()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/views/pages/tmpl/default.php:32
2  include()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/HtmlView.php:701
3  Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->loadTemplate()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/View/HtmlView.php:230
4  Joomla\CMS\MVC\View\HtmlView->display()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/views/pages/view.html.php:55
5  SppagebuilderViewPages->display()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:664

Comment: and this : 6  Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->display()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/controller.php:23
7  SppagebuilderController->display()  JROOT/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:702
8  Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController->execute()  JROOT/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/sppagebuilder.php:27
9  require_once()  JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:402

Comment: and this : 10  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent()  JROOT/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php:377
11  Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent()  JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:101
12  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()  JROOT/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php:159
13  Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()  JROOT/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php:225
14  Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()  JROOT/administrator/index.php:51

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you edit your original post and put the stack trace into your original post rather than the comments.

Comment: I think this is still an issue for the vendor of SP Page Builder. The error, coming from the Vendors template, is saying that it found the SppagebuilderViewPages file but it was not able to find a method/function in that file called getSortFields

Comment: I found the function in  `/home2/lach3224/public_html/administrator/components/com_sppagebuilder/views/pages/tmpl/default.php:32` and it's `$sortFields = $this->getSortFields();`

I've tried to change this function and it change something but i don't know what to change to fix it

Comment: I don't have SP Page Builder code to be able find where the getSortField() is or should be but again as it is the Vendors code it is really up to them to provide the support to fix the issue in their code. There doesn't appear to be any overrides on your part.

Comment: I try to contact them but it's very difficult to get help with Joomla !